# Need help to develop simple Sharepoint 2013 app to upload excel files to a library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I spun up a new windows 2012 Server R2, installed Sharepoint 2013, and Visual Studio 2019 with the Office/Sharepoint dev options on an old Dell server.  I'm trying to write and debug an app I found on the web to upload excel files from a shared drive to a sharepoint document library.  I'm at the point where everytime I try to run this app, I get an error stating:

> The Web application at http://tcaserver01/my/MPR could not be found.
> Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be
> serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a
> new request URL mapping to the intended application.

I just need a bit of hand-holding to get things properly configured I think. However, when I put in the url in a web browser, it shows the empty library fine.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace SPTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            String site = "http://tcaserver01/my/MPR";      //URL of SharePoint site
            String library = "Review_Workbooks";            //Library Name
            String filePath = @"S:\MPR\MPR Template.xlsx";  //Entire path of file to upload

            try
            {
                using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(site))
                {
                    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        //Check if file exists in specified path
                        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                            Console.WriteLine("Error - Specified file not found.");

                        //Get handle of library
                        SPFolder spLibrary = spWeb.Folders[library];

                        //Extract file name (file will be uploaded with this name)
                        String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                        //Read file for uploading
                        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

                        //Replace existing file
                        Boolean replaceExistingFile = true;

                        //Upload document to library
                        SPFile spfile = spLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFile);
                        spfile.CheckIn("file uploaded via code");
                        spLibrary.Update();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully !!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error uploading file - " + exp.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems when I logged in as the Sharepoint admin user account, I was able to move further in the app, successfully opening up the Sharepoint site.  So, when I was logged in as myself, I must not have had the appropriate permissions to open the site.  So, this question should be closed as I can now get past what was blocking me. Thanks for anyone who may have read this question already!